# Why isn't my component rerendered when I change the state in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why isn't my Chart component re-rendered when I change the state with `setState` in `componentDidMount`?

I want to fetch the data from the database and when they are loaded, render the chart. Instead, the chart is rendered with empty data and the data from the database isn't shown.

```
    changeJoystick = () => {
        this.setState({robustActive: !this.state.robustActive, compactActive: !this.state.compactActive});
    };

    async fetchHeatMapData() {
        let robustData = [];
        let compactData = [];
        try {
            let response = await getDoubleAxisSegmentAverage();
            robustData = response.data;
            let {seriesRobust} = this.state;
            robustData = robustData.slice(1, 37);
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                seriesRobust[i].data = robustData.slice(6 * i, 6 * (i + 1));
            }
            return seriesRobust;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchHeatMapData()
            .then(seriesRobust => {
                    this.setState({seriesRobust});
                    console.log(this.state.seriesRobust);
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        let robust_variant = this.state.robustActive ? 'contained' : 'outlined';
        let compact_variant = this.state.compactActive ? 'contained' : 'outlined';

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Grid container direction='row' justify='flex-start'>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Button variant={robust_variant} color='secondary' onClick={this.changeJoystick.bind(this)}>Robust
                            Joystick</Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Button variant={compact_variant} color='secondary'
                                onClick={this.changeJoystick.bind(this)}>Compact
                            Joystick</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <br/>
                <Grid container justify='space-evenly'>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Chart
                            options={this.state.options}
                            series={this.state.robustActive ? this.state.seriesRobust : 
                             this.state.seriesCompact}
                            type='heatmap'
                            width={1000}
                            height={1000}/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: What does the network tab show you? Is data fetched, or does it return an empty array?

Comment: Is `robustActive` falsey, therefore setting the `series` prop value to `seriesCompact` which looks to still be an empty array (since it isn't updated in `componentDidMount`)?

Comment: the console.log(this.state.seriesRobust) shows a filled array, so the data is correctly fetched from the database

Comment: FYI, that console.log in the promise chain is logging the current value of `this.state.seriesRobust`, not the next state value after state is updated. If you want to log the state after the update then you need to use the callback parameter `this.setState({seriesRobust}, () => console.log(this.state.seriesRobust));`

Comment: I think you need to show more code, I don't see anything particularly wrong with the code provided.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend against using class based components and switching to React Hooks and functional components. Especially if it's a new codebase, and even more especially if you're just learning React. Knowing class based component structure will help you with development, in the workplace, and better understanding npm modules, but functional components are faster, better and yield cleaner code.

Comment: @Nadine try `const seriesRobust = [...this.state.seriesRobust]` instead of `let {seriesRobust} = this.state;`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>     this.fetchHeatMapData()
>         .then(seriesRobust => {
>                 this.setState({seriesRobust});
>                 console.log(this.state.seriesRobust);
>             }
>         )
> }
> ```

You should not expect updated state value just after setState call!! Mayority of `'setState not rerendered'` questions is about this.

You can do just

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchHeatMapData()
}
```

and `setState()` inside `fetchHeatMapData()` instead of return

> ```
>         let {seriesRobust} = this.state;
> ```

this code uses the same ref for object, it's enough to

```
        const seriesRobust = [...this.state.seriesRobust]
```

`this.state.seriesRobust` is almost NOT USED in render, it's used conditionally (only if `robustActive` is true)

> series={this.state.robustActive ? this.state.seriesRobust :

Comment: I applied your suggestions. I changed the conditional rendering to
series={this.state.seriesRobust}. 
But the re-rendering is still not triggered. How can I achive the re-rendering?

Comment: show updated code, initial state ... check in react dev tools `<Chart/>` properties - changes? Maybe inside `<Chart/>` problem?

Comment: you can also use `console.log(this.state.seriesRobust)` in `render`

Comment: in the react dev tools in the chart component the array values are updated and when I do the `console.log` in `render` also.

Comment: Chart component internal fault

Comment: So is my only option to switch to another chart library?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
            this.fetchHeatMapData().then(() => this.forceUpdate());
    }
```

In the `fetchHeatMapData()` function I set the state with
`this.setState({seriesRobust});`

When the data has been fetched I'm doing a `forceUpdate` in `componentDidMount()` and now it's working as I intended.

I know that you should usually avoid using `forceUpdate()` but this is the only solution I can think of right now.